# Ng Touch MouseUp Doesn't Apply

Tags: angularjs

I have a plunk here:

**https://plnkr.co/edit/EKpqNwQEHHHiFoiv43s3**

I am having an issue where my ng-touch on a phone or tablet is firing on the mousedown but not on the mouseup, resulting in the incrementation going on *ad infinitum* which is not desired.

Code here:

```
$scope.mouseDown = function(dir) { //this function fires when I press down on a phone
    promise = $interval(function() {
      if (dir === "up")
        $scope.quantity++;
      else
        $scope.quantity--;
    }, 100);

  };

  $scope.mouseUp = function() { //this function doesn't seem to fire when I stop the press on a phone
    $interval.cancel(promise);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`mouseup` does not fire on touch devices. `ngTouch` does not give you directives to bind touch events unfortunately. You'll need to grab a custom directive that will allow you to bind `touchstart` and `touchend` events. There are a few out there. I've created a gist with one I've written that has worked well for me on several projects:

https://gist.github.com/Toddses/fdd862648e10530038550e253212d9c1

With this, as is, you can bind `flux-touchstart` and `flux-touchend` in the markup the same way you bind `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup`.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought mouseup was converted to a touchend just like mosedown is converted to a touchstart. It seems to be covered in the ng-touch source code.

Comment: That may be correct, but I have never seen that to be true. And your example is technically correct and it doesn't work. My advice is to target touch and mouse events to cover everything instead of relying on mouse events to work across the board.

Comment: Where are you getting `touchstart` and `touchend` from in your answer? Can you give an implementation in the plunker?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more relevant angular information, plus an example directive for binding `touchstart` and `touchend`, which is not offered in `ngTouch`.